# Correct way to work with database realtime

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm currently in a project in which I'm testing `firebase`. I have some problems. I would like to know what are the best practices of working with firebase .....

One of the problems is that I will work with multiple nodes and I do not know if it is advisable to call the data with promises in this way .....

```js
let oneData = new Promise( res => {
    one.on('value', s => {
    let a = res(s.val());
        return a;
    });
});

let twoData = new Promise( res => {
    two.on('value', s => {
    let a = res(s.val());
        return a;
    });
});

oneData.then(d =>{
    console.log(d);
    // work data
});

twoData.then(d =>{
    console.log(d);
    // work data
});
```

the problem is that I imagine that I would lose the realtime listener, I am confused about how to merge the data of several nodes and work quietly knowing that they are available ..... what I have done is to do it this way ... .

```
one.on('value', a => {
  two.on('value', b => {
    tree.on('value', c => {
        // work data
    });
  });
});
```

I thank this community for the help and knowledge they can share, thank you!

Comment: A promise is not an event listener and wont function in the way you expect it to. You already have the event listener, `one.on` so just use that.

Comment: @AdamH if I know, I even mention it, now would be like calling all the nodes that I need in the right way to work with your data, one by one, retiring its value? or together as I put it at the end of my post? thanks

Comment: Your question is a little unclear, what exactly are you trying to do? Are you trying to listen for an event raised from the DB and then react to it? What are `one` and `two`?

Comment: `one` and  `two` are examples of nodes that I want to hear from the database ... what I want is to work together with data several nodes .... I do not know if the final example is advisable .... @AdamH

Comment: When you say 'work together with data several nodes' what does that mean? Are you wanting to access data from both nodes at the same time?

Comment: If correct, that's what I mean ...sorry for my english, I use translator. @AdamH

Comment: Don't worry about your English, I just wanted to make sure I was understanding you. You are looking for a Join. In Firebase this is a bit tricky but this link should help you solve your problem. https://kieldev.wordpress.com/2017/01/30/firebase-advance-querying-join-reference/